# Como puedo mostrar este resultado. JSON ENCODE

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo el siguiente codigo donde guardo variables en un array y aparte guarda 2 array de informacion dentro de este.

```
  $fonos =array();
  $direccion = array();

        foreach ($_POST['new_fono'] as $fono) {
            $fonos[] = $fono;
          }

        foreach ($_POST['new_address'] as $address) {
            $direccion[] = $address;
          }


   $data['result'] = array($name,$city,$obs,$email,$giro,$direccion,$fonos);
   echo json_encode($data);;
```

De esta forma muestro las varibales guardaras

```
alert(response.result[0]);
```

Pero como muestro el `array` fonos y direccion.

---

Mi resultado en devtool

```
{"result":["Name Cliente","City","qwe","mail@mail.com","Informatica",["Calle 1","Calle 2","Calle 3"],["123123123","456456456","789789789"]]}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Comparte el resultado de console.log(response);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dentro de la clave `result` del JSON lo que hay es un array con varios elementos, y dentro de ese array hay otros dos sub-arrays, uno con las calles y y otro con los teléfonos.

Una forma de leer el JSON sería una lectura normal por cada clave, preguntando cuando ésta sea un array, en cuyo caso puedes valerte de `join` para sacar los datos que haya en los sub-arrays, con un separador cualquiera, que puede ser salto de línea, una coma, u otro.

Por ejemplo:

```js
var respuesta =
`
{
 "result": ["Name Cliente", "City", "qwe", "mail@mail.com", "Informatica", ["Calle 1", "Calle 2", "Calle 3"],
  ["123123123", "456456456", "789789789"]
 ]
}
`;

json = JSON.parse(respuesta);
arr = json.result
arr.forEach(function(k) {
  if (Array.isArray(k)) {
    console.log(k.join('\n'));
  } else {
    console.log(k);
  }
});
```

> #### NOTA ACLARATORIA
>
> A pesar de que se han ofrecido varias respuestas, por algún motivo curioso no me queda claro todavía **de qué lado**
>   quieres leer/mostrar los datos ¿? Supongo que estás trayendo un JSON
>   del servidor (mediante PHP) y que quieres mostrarlo en el cliente
>   (mediante Javascript). Ese sería el escenario más real, mediante una
>   petición Ajax (supongo).
>
> En cambio, si quieres leer/mostrar los datos del lado del servidor
>   estaríamos ante un caso extraño. No le veo sentido a meter los datos
>   en un JSON para luego trabajarlos, leerlos, mostrarlos en el mismo
>   servidor. Cuando se convierte a JSON generalmente es para
>   *transportar* los datos, entiéndase, para devolverlos al cliente (se usa JSON para ese *transporte* por ser un formato ligero y práctico).
>
> Agradecería que aclares ese punto en tu pregunta: **¿De qué lado quieres leer/mostrar los datos, del lado del servidor o del lado del cliente?** Si fuera del lado del servidor, tendrías quizá que aclarar algunas preguntas que surgirian sobre la lógica que aplicas para hacerlo de esa manera.

Comment: Me funciono esta respuesta   `$.each(response.result['fonos'], function( index, value ) { alert(value) }`

Comment: @MoteCL es la misma lógica explicada en mi respuesta. La diferencia es que el código que muestras es jQuery y el mío es Javascript puro (recomendable) porque es el lenguaje nativo del navegador, mientras que jQuery, aunque muy repandido, no deja de ser una librería y por tanto funciona más lento que JS puro.

Answer (score 3):

de la misma forma que imprimes pero debes usar **[json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)** para convertir el array a String:

```
echo json_encode($fonos);
echo json_encode($direccion);
```

para mostrar en un alert, muestra el array como representación String del objeto de esta forma:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('".json_encode($fonos)."') </script>";

echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('".json_encode($direccion)."') </script>";
```

---

Ejemplo:

```
$names = array( "elenasys", "doru", "jorgesys", "ionana", "nicoleta", "angela");

echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('".json_encode($names)."') </script>";
```

mostraría:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

De acuerdo al json que muestras en tu actualización:

La estructura en realidad es un array (`result`) que dentro contiene 5 valores (`"Name Cliente", "City", "qwe", "mail@mail.com", "Informatica"`) y 2 arrays, uno conteniendo las calles (`["Calle 1", "Calle 2", "Calle 3"]`) y otro conteniendo los números (`["123123123", "456456456", "789789789"]`)

```
{
    "result": ["Name Cliente", "City", "qwe", "mail@mail.com", "Informatica", ["Calle 1", "Calle 2", "Calle 3"],
        ["123123123", "456456456", "789789789"]
    ]
}
```

Para obtener sus valores puedes realizarlo de esta forma:

```
   $json = '{"result":["Name Cliente","City","qwe","mail@mail.com","Informatica",["Calle 1","Calle 2","Calle 3"],["123123123","456456456","789789789"]]}'; 
    $response = extract(json_decode($json,true));

foreach ($result as $valor){

  if(is_array($valor)){ //Detecta si es array.

   foreach ($valor as $valorArray) { //Imprime valores en array       
    echo 'valor: '.$valorArray.'<br>';
   }

  } else { 
    echo 'valor: '.$valor.'<br>';
  }

}
```

Esto tendría como salida:

```
valor: Name Cliente
valor: City
valor: qwe
valor: mail@mail.com
valor: Informatica
valor: Calle 1
valor: Calle 2
valor: Calle 3
valor: 123123123
valor: 456456456
valor: 789789789
```

Comment: Subire una foto de del json enconde

Comment: @MoteCL ok ahora entiendo que tienes : {"result":["Name Cliente","City","qwe","mail@mail.com","Informatica",["Calle 1","Calle 2","Calle 3"],["123123123","456456456","789789789"]]} y de aquí quieres obtener los nombres

Comment: los numeros y direcciones en un foreach

Comment: La estructura de tu json es diferente a lo que preguntabas inicialmente pero bueno para obtener estos valores , lo realizarías de esta forma :  foreach ($result[5] as $valor) {
    echo $valor.'<br>';
}
foreach ($result[6] as $valor) {
    echo $valor.'<br>';
}        Revisa mi actualización @MoteCL y revisa lo que indico acerca de la estructura de tu json

Comment: Esta data quiero mostrarla en mi success de ajax

Answer (score 2):

mi consejo es que definas tu objeto result con clave-valor. Podrias hacerlo asi:

```
$fonos =array();
  $direccion = array();

        foreach ($_POST['new_fono'] as $fono) {
            $fonos[] = $fono;
          }

        foreach ($_POST['new_address'] as $address) {
            $direccion[] = $address;
          }


   $data['result'] = array(
      'name' => $name,
      'city' => $city,
      'obs'  => $obs,
      'email'=> $email,
      'giro' => $giro,
      'direccion' => $direccion,
      'telefonos' => $fonos
   );
   echo json_encode($data);
```

Con ello, ahora acceder a cada elemento es mas facil, podrias acceder como:

```
alert(response.result['city']);
```

Además, con esto estas definiendo una estructura que es facil de entender en la recepcion (al leer el json, se puede ver que la clave `name` hace referencia al nombre). De la otra manera tendrias que indicarle al destinatario que el 0 es name, 1 es direccion...

Comment: Pero como deberia recorrer el `$direccion` siendo que es un array?

Comment: podrias utilizar `response.result['direccion'].join(' ')`. Esto te mostraria cada elemento del array separados por un espacio. Otra cosa es que necesites mostrarlos en una tabla: en ese caso tendras que recorrer cada elemento de ese array con un foreach.

Comment: Y si quiero poder recorrer ese array en un foreach o loop para mostrar los numeros

Comment: como te digo anteriormente, si necesitas mostrarlos en una tabla o algo asi, tienes que recorrer cada elemento. En la respuesta de @A.cedano tienes como recorrer ese array en javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Así puedes mostrarlo:

```
<br>
Dirección:<br>
alert(response.result[5]);<br>
Fonos:<br>
alert(response.result[6]);<br>
```

o en todo caso has un `console.log(response.result);` para que veas por consola tu array